# Reading from a .txt file

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

You are given a text file (customer.txt) in which name, lastname and age of customers are stored:

```
Ali Aslan 25 
Ayse Demir 35 
Ahmet Gemici 17 .
.
.
```

You should process this file and find number of customers for each of the following ranges:

```
0 - 19 
20 - 59 
60 -
```

This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ass11 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("customer.txt"));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("file customer.txt not found");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        int next, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, sum = 0;
        while(inputStream.hasNextInt()) {
            next = inputStream.nextInt();
            sum = sum + next;
            if (next >= 60)
                x++;
            else if (next >= 19 && next <= 59)
                y++;
            else
               z++;
        }
        inputStream.close();
        System.out.println(x + " customer bigger than 60");
        System.out.println(y + " customer between 19 and 59");
        System.out.println(z + " customers smaller then 19");
    }
}
```

It reads only numbers. When I write a name and surname to the text file, it doesn't work and I don't use the `split()` method...

Comment: Please use a capital `I` rather than this strange symbol. And define "it doesn't work". What happens precisely? Also, if all you use is nextInt(), why do you think it should read names in your file? What could you possibly use in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html to read the next token as a string?

Comment: why do you expect it to work for other than integers, when you explicitly call `nextInt`?

Comment: Muco, are you not allowed to use split() ?

Comment: No,I do not know how to use the split method

Comment: @muco Example: `"a_b_c".split("_")` evaluates to the same thing as `new String[]{"a", "b", "c"}`. It splits the string you call it on by the given parameter and returns the result as a `String` array.

Comment: @muco - Can you give me 1 upvote for my answer ? (you will need to get 15 points minimum for it). Someone downvoted me for helping you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. It works.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class MyProject {

    public static void main(String [] args){
      String path = "C:/temp/stack/scores.txt";
      processTextFile(path);    
    }

    public static void processTextFile(String filePath) {

        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
            String line = br.readLine();
            String [] tokens = null;
            int score = 0;
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            int z = 0;

            while (line != null) {
                tokens = line.split(" ");
                score = Integer.parseInt(tokens[tokens.length -1]);

                if(score >= 0 && score < 20){
                    x++;
                }
                if(score >= 20 && score < 60){
                    y++;
                }
                if(score > 60){
                    z++;
                }

                line = br.readLine();
            }

            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }

            System.out.println("0-20 = " + x + ", 20-60 = " + y + ", 60+ = " + z);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Really? "Try this code. it works." SO is not a site for 'gimme the codes', it is a site for explaining where your error is and suggestions for how to fix it. Please do not answer 'Here is a working piece of code that completely rewrites yours but gives the expected output', answer '_ is how you could think about this, you are going wrong by doing _'. It helps other users as well as the OP to be able to fix other situations like this, in a generalised way.

Comment: @bcsb1001 - This answer is selected and I cannot even delete it. Please undo your downvote. The last thing I need is more downvotes on this.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend testing with the original file:

```
Ali Aslan 25 
Ayse Demir 35 
Ahmet Gemici 17
```

Each line is a name plus age, so you would get a code like:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("path/to/file" ), "UTF-8"));

String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] contents = line.split(" ");
    // Assume contents is 3 long: name, surname, age
    System.out.printf("%s %s is %d", contents[0], contents[1], Integer.parseInt(contents[2]));
}
```

Yes, this does make use of the split method, which makes it easier in my opinion. You could also use the Scanner by calling it in a loop with `next()`, `next()` and `nextInt()`

Comment: By `nextLine()`, you mean `next()`, right? The two names aren't on separate lines...

Comment: Yes, I will fix that. Beg my pardon :P